# Create Jar Library Without a Main Class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, program-entry-point

Today I have just created a Java Library. I created it using a Main class, since IntelliJ IDEA 14 asked me to add one. However I want it to be a normal library, without any Main classes. Is it possible to create a jar file from such a project without having a single class with the main method? If so, how do you create such a jar.

It just seems a bit silly to have a main method if you never use it.

Comment: How *exactly* did you tell IntelliJ to make the jar file, and how *exactly* did it prompt you? I suspect you chose an option which implied that you *did* want a Main class.

Comment: "Create jar file from module with dependencies"

Comment: The main class is just a line in the MANIFEST.MF used when running with "-jar".  In other cases it should behave as you want.

Comment: Yes, but since it is a library this class will be available in it too. It just seems weird to add a class in that has no function whatsoever.

Comment: just delete the Main class. You didn't need to create it in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it in few ways, for example from command line, from IDE, maven or other build tool, I describe 2 ways:

**Command line:**

You can create jar file from command line (without IDE), Here is reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

where `jar-file` is .jar file name you want and `input-file(s)` are files you want to put inside your library (can be a wildcard, e.g.: `*.class`)

**Intellij Idea:**

Create Artifact like in this article, but without specifying Main class http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/

Then click *Build > Build artifact > Build*.

This works even if there is no Main class.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out! Just seems weird that when I place the new library in another project it still shows the Main class in the library folder. Is that normal?

Comment: Is Main class in library?

Comment: This is a poor answer, showing pictures of some (other) IDE when there is a more appropriate (documented, non-IDE-specific) method.

Comment: I thought, the question was: how to do it inside IntelliJ - there are answers how to it from command line. I eddited answer and put this possibility into it.

Comment: Question (succinctly) was: "Is it possible to create a jar file [] without having a single class with the main method? If so, how do you create such a jar."

Comment: Anytime I can avoid the command line I will take it. Thank you dey.

Comment: @dey has an answer... and it is correct but, practically speaking, OP should use (some) build tool like Maven (MVN). It is built into all IDEs (including IntelliJ - which is great) but the big realization here is that "not an IDE makes a system". From code > build > deploy ... that "build" step won't take place in an IDE at any development shop so, just recommending the introduction of a build step and tool that is IDE-independent (so for example someone else can download from GIT, build and deploy).

Answer (score 11):

Use a build tool like Maven (no IDE dependencies but can be called from IDE for convenience) with the shade plugin to create an 'uber' JAR (that includes all needed dependencies into one final JAR for the project)...

"pom.xml"

...

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
       <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Documentation to Shade plugin:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: Agreed that this should be the "correct" answer.  There should not be any dependencies on IDE.

Comment: Indeed - there are FAR too many posts about programming that dive into IDE details, which have nothing to do with the languages or any eventual server-side "run-time" implementation.